# Microsoft Teams Bot - Does the teamsAppId change?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using the Graph API to proactively install a Teams bot for all users in an organization.

I need to retrieve the `teamsAppId` by `externalId` like so :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps?$filter=externalId eq '{IdFromManifest}'
```

Is it safe to query the `teamsAppId` once and keep it in the appSettings?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=dotnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an app is published to the Microsoft Teams apps catalog an unique id (`teamsAppId`) is generated for the app and this id is immutable and can be stored in the `appSettings`.

I'm storing `teamsAppId` in the local SQLite db and I've never had a problem with id's immutability.

Answer (score 0):

When a teams app is first published to your organization, e.g. during development or in-house only usage (distributionMethod = "organization" in the catalog from the `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps` API request), the `id` field is generated by the catalog system and the `externalId` field is set to the teams app id ({IdFromManifest} in your example, and as seen in dev.teams.microsoft.com > Apps > App Id).

However, when it has been approved and published to the app store, it is a new app entry in the catalog with the `id` set to the teams app id ({IdFromManifest}) that was previously the "externalId" of the organization distributed app, and with `externalId` set to null.

See suggested documentation change for the api here for clarification:  https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/22146 (approved 2023-07-19)

Note that it is possible that you'll see both apps in the catalog if it was published both to the store and your organization, so querying using the {IdFromManifest} value as either the id or externalId will return both apps, which you'll have to handle.

Assuming for the purpose of development and then production release, I would recommend implementing the $filter so that you check either fields and the use the distributionMethod for selecting.

e.g.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps?$filter=(id eq '{IdFromManifest}' and distributionMethod eq 'store') or (externalId eq '{IdFromManifest}' and distributionMethod eq 'organization')
```

and using logic to determine the correct app you wish to use depending on the dev environment and the distribution method, or

alternatively you can just query with first `id eq '{IdFromManifest}' or externalId eq '{IdFromManifest}'` and select the correct one using the distributionMethod base on your need.